# Create a fourth col based on three other cols in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the data set I have

```
col1 | col2 | col3
E    |   1.2| 1.1
E    | 2.5  | 1.5
E    | 3.4  | 7.2
T    | 1.0  |5.4
T    |  2.1 | 1.2
```

What I want is a fourth col based on the above cols, so if col1 == 'E' then col4 will take col2 value and if col1 =='T', then col4 will take col3 value.

I have tried loops and np.where but nothing is working and I am constantly getting only value for col2. which is wrong where col1 is T.

This is one of the last pieces of code I tried, but failed:

```
col4= []
for i in range(0,len(data_set['col1'])):
try:     
    subdf = data_set['col1'].loc[(data_set['col1']=='E')]
    curve = data_set['col2']

    print(curve)
except:

    subdf = data_set.loc[(data_set['col1']=='T')]
    curve =data_set['col3']

    print(curve)
```

Comment: In your case a simple: `curve = np.where(data_set.col1 == 'E', data_set.col2, data_set.col3)` looks like it's what you're after. (don't forget the `import numpy as np` though)

Comment: Jon does that mean I dont need a for loop?
sorry your response wasnt clear 
i am very new to python

Comment: yeah... explicitly looping over dataframes or arrays is something you should be wary of and try to avoid unless you really, really have no other way of achieving the result. However, pandas/numpy offer a *lot* of operations that efficiently do things for you and loop efficiently at a lower level themselves.

Comment: Just use the single command above - then look at `curve` - it should be what you want if you've only got E and T in your table... If it's E you get the value from one column, otherwise, you get the value from the other...

Comment: OMG you are a genious!! Thank you so much..
I am so going to use Stackoverflow for my learning and questions from now on.
Thanks AGAIN!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are looking for something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

data = [["E", 1.2, 1.1],
        ["E", 2.5, 1.5],
        ["E", 3.4, 7.2],
        ["T", 1.0, 5.4],
        ["T", 2.1, 1.2]]

def transform(data):
    result = []
    for line in data:
        tmp = line[:]
        value = line[1] if line[0] == "E" else line[2]
        tmp.append(value)
        result.append(tmp)
    return result

print(transform(data))
```

First, please have a look at how loops work in Python:

Though technically `for i in range(0,len(data_set['col1']))` might seem correct, since in typical `C` based languages this is the basic for loop, in python the `iterator` pattern is used to loop. Typically `for foo in foocollection`.

`try`, `except` is not, what you want in this case. These are keywords for dealing with *exceptional* behaviour. Here, you expect some things without exception.

In my example, I make some assumptions:

1) data is a list of lines (lists)

2) you do not want to modify the original. So a copy is made on the fly: python allows to use the `[:]` notation, to do that

3) there are only "E"s and "T"s, so a basic `if` `else` works

The code should produce the wanted result and is a first help to get into Python ;)

Have fun!

Comment: Thats a great answer @Thomas. Thanks for all the details. It really is helpful. I am learning to get better at loops

Comment: would you be kind to explain me why you used
tmp = line[:] in your code.
What it does. (some elaboration)
Many Thanks

Comment: Typically, you access elements of a list with `line[x]`. Then, there is slicing, which gives you a subset of a list. In Python you do that with `line[start:end]`. If you leave one parameter out, python takes the outmost possibe point. So `line[:]`is an edge case of that, where you want a slice starting at the first element and ending at the end of the list - which results in a copy. That's the whole magic 